# Which fridge consumes more energy? One with big mass in it vs one with small mass in it?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life

We have two containers (the fridges) each made of the same thermal insulation. They both consume continuously energy just enough so that their inside temperature stays the same. They consume energy because the insulation is not perfect. Which consumes more energy the one with more mass in it, or the one with one less mass in it? I know that it took more energy to cool down the big mass, but now it is cool, we just maintain the temperature. I suspect that now they consume the same energy, but I am not sure.

[image]

Comment: Once cool, the only issue is heat loss to the outside world, not what is insides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the temperature is static, and the only work is heat transport from outside to inside through the insulation and from inside to outside via the heat engine, there's no difference. Heat transport per unit time at constant temperature distribution across a barrier is a function of barrier conductivity, surface area, barrier thickness, barrier shape, barrier emissivity, convective heat transfer coefficient of the barrier, and temperature difference, but not of enclosed mass.

Probably obviously, if you have a mass of plutonium or rotting vegetables or squirrels eating nuts inside the refrigerator, they make more heat and it takes more energy for the heat engine to move it outside.

Answer (score 3):

For real refrigerators that get opened and closed, the ones with more mass require less energy than the ones with less mass.  That is because there is less air in those and hence less outside air to cool down after each opening.

Comment: I think this also depends on how long you keep the door open. If it's opened only briefly, this answer makes sense. If it is open for a long time, the mass can absorb more heat, requiring more energy to be cooled down after the door is closed.

Comment: Rather, the one with larger free air volume spends more energy for recooling after the open/close cycle, as more of cold air is replaced by warm air from the room.

Answer (score -1):

Let's see it differently,

My answer is clearly **NO** they consume different amount of energy.

From image in question both refrigerators are made up of two phases, ref 1 has more of solid phase than gaseous phase as compared to ref 2 where gaseous phase is more. Since specific heat capacities of both phases are different there's no way they will need same amount of heat to be heated, depending on what solid we have which ref will consume more heat will vary, but generally we can say that ref 1 will take more heat since it has more mass than than ref 2.

Just a small note that maintaining temperature is same as heating so it is immaterial to our discussion.

Comment: I really appreciate that you added a different answer to my question. If we accept this answer as correct, we have to find out why the other answers are not correct. Where is the flaw in their logic?

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because it is false. Heat is related to specific heat capacity by the *change* in temperature of the relevant mass $Q=Cm\Delta T$

Comment: @David they are neglecting the fact that maintaining temperature is same reheating/recooling the system to original temperature and heat needed obviously depends on mass of system. They are not providing false information but I think they are not analysing the system properly

Comment: Is maintaining the temperature same as reheating/recooling? I am not sure, let's say it is. Let's say the content of the fridge on the left has double the heat capacity. In this case, its temperature will increase half as much as the fridge on the right. Next question is, how much energy the fridge will consume to cool it back. If the energy consumption is linear in terms of the heat capacity and temperature change, than the two systems will consume the same energy. By heat capacity I mean specific heat capacity multiplied by mass.